# Jackson Json deserialize date string to java date

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I have to read date string from json and set it to java object.

I have used the following annotations on my variable.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RequestObject {

    @JsonProperty("doj")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class, as=Date.class)
    private Date doj;

    public Date getDoj() {
        return doj;
    }
    public void setDoj(Date doj) {
        this.doj = doj;
    }
}
```

Below is my Custom DateDeserializer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>{

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try{
            return sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(ParseException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I am testing this using postman, below is my postman request.

```
{
    "doj":"2017-12-27"
}
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2017-12-27" is too short
        at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945) ~[joda-time-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at com.exxonmobil.ace.hybris.jaxb.DateAdapter.unmarshal(DateAdapter.java:45) ~[DateAdapter.class:?]
        at com.exxonmobil.ace.hybris.jaxb.DateAdapter.unmarshal(DateAdapter.java:1) ~[DateAdapter.class:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.XMLJavaTypeConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(XMLJavaTypeConverter.java:149) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.1.jar:?]
```

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: where do you use joda-time? Is it full stacktrace? on which line error occurs?

Comment: Try using the Jackson java 8 module. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8